# MySQL error 1064 Create table with foriegn keys

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Create Table IF NOT EXISTS Advisors 
(
AdvisorID int primary Key auto_increment Not Null,
FirstName char(50),
LastName char(50),
`EmailAddr` varchar(100)
);

Create Table IF NOT EXISTS Students 
(
StudentID int auto_increment not null primary key,
FirstName Char(50),
LastName char(50),
BirthDate date,
Gender Char(6),
StartDate date,
GPA numeric(3,0),
IsActive bit,
Bio text,
AdvisorID int,
foreign key (AdvisorID) references Advisors(AdvisorID)
);

create table IF NOT EXISTS Classes
(
ClassID int primary Key auto_increment not null,
ClassCode varchar(50),
ClassName char(100),
Description varchar(500)
);

create table IF NOT exists Students_Classes
(
StudentClassID int primary key auto_increment not null,
StudentID int,
ClassID int,
StartDate date,
Assignment1 int(100),
Assignment2 int(100),
Assignment3 int(100),
Assignment4 int(100),
ClassGPA numeric(3,0),
foreign key StudentID REFERENCES Students(StudentID),
foreign key ClassID REFERENCES Classes(ClassID)
);
```

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REFERENCES Students(StudentID), foreign key ClassID REFERENCES Classes(ClassID) ' at line 12

I have tried to remove the References and see where that gets me is just a different error

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' foreign key ClassID )' at line 12

Which makes the StudentID work but the ClassID doesn't.I have also tried to use Classes(ClassID) but that does not work.

Comment: Use the same syntax as your `foreign key (AdvisorID)` -- the parens `()` are required.= `foreign key (StudentID) REFERENCES...`

Comment: Note about MySQL syntax 1064 errors - the place to look for the problem is to the thing immediately before the reported `use near....` message. In this case, the `StudentID` right before `REFERENCES` missing `()`.

Comment: Without `()` the text `StudentID` is interpreted as the name of the index, which cannot be the same as a field name and the list of fields will also be missing.

Comment: Thanks It worked with that! Syntax Strikes again!